# MySQL CallableStatement.getObject have inconsistent behavior

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, callable-statement, out-parameters

I have the following simple procedure defined within in a test schema, `_test_jdbc_inconsistency`, in an instance of MySQL on my development system

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _test_jdbc_inconsistency.proc(IN param1 boolean, OUT param2 boolean)
BEGIN
  IF (param1 IS NULL)
  THEN
    SET param2 = NULL;
  ELSE
    set param2 = not param1;
  END IF;
END
```

But much to my surprise, the following simple test fails

```
@Test(dataProvider = "connectionPool")
public void testJdbcInconsitencyOutParameterType(Connection con) throws SQLException, IOException
{
    con.setCatalog("_test_jdbc_inconsistency");
    try (CallableStatement statement = con.prepareCall("{call proc(?, ?)}"))
    {
        statement.setInt("param1", 5);
        statement.registerOutParameter("param2", Types.INTEGER);
        statement.execute();

        assertTrue(statement.getObject(2) instanceof Integer);
        assertEquals(statement.getObject(2), 25);
        assertTrue(statement.getObject("param2") instanceof Integer);
    }
}
```

The inconsistency is flagged on last `assertTrue` statement; while calling the overload of `CallableStatement.getObject` which accepts a parameter-index returns a result of expected type (`java.lang.Integer`), the other overload accepting parameter-name returns inconsistent result of type `java.lang.Long`. Since I'm using signed integers and based on many instructions on using *out parameters* with JDBC, specifically the one provided by [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html), the process seems correct and this looks like an **inconsistent behavior**.

Can anyone else confirm this issue?

My Environment:

- Windows 8.1 x64
- JDK 1.8.0_45 (x64/x86)
- MySQL Connector/J 5.1.34
- MySQL Server 5.6.24
- TestNG 6.9.5

Answer (score 0):

Since there have been no comment or response, I reported this to MySQL bug database and it's been accepted and verified as a bug.
Here is the link to the issue for those interested:

https://bugs.mysql.com/?id=77766